# How to put an image in the same position of the Camera2D?

Tags: c#, xna

I need to put an image in the same position of the camera. If it is moveing i want the image to move too but i don't know the parameters of the position.I have started programming in xna and c# some months ago so I don't know anything about it. Is you need more informations just ask.  This is my camera2D code:

```
public class Camera
{
    public Matrix trasform;
    public Matrix Trasform
    {
        get { return trasform; }
    }
    private Vector2 center;
    private Viewport view;

    public Camera(Viewport newView)
    {
        view = newView;
    }

    public void Update(Vector2 position, int xOffset, int yOffset)
    {
        if (position.X < view.Width / 2)
            center.X = view.Width / 2;
        else if (position.X > xOffset - (view.Width / 2))
            center.X = xOffset - (view.Width / 2);
        else center.X = position.X;

        if (position.Y < view.Height / 2)
            center.Y = view.Height / 2;
        else if (position.Y > yOffset - (view.Height / 2))
            center.Y = yOffset - (view.Height / 2);
        else center.Y = position.Y;

        trasform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-center.X + (view.Width / 2),
            -center.Y + (view.Height / 2), 0));

    }
}
```

I think I have to use the viewport but i don't know all its functions and i haven't found anything on internet.

Comment: I need to know that for putting the score on the screen.

Comment: Your question is about drawing and I don't see any Draw code.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your problem, you are using the `transformMatrix` parameter of `spriteBatch.Begin` to draw your game.
If you need to add some 2D graphics on screen (score, times...) you need to open another `spriteBatch` without the `transformMatrix`, in this way every coordinate you use in your `spriteBatch.Draw` or `DrawString` corresponds to your screen coordinate.